# How to compile a document with EPS images using TeXnicCenter?

Tags: graphics, pdf, compiling, eps, texniccenter

I have all my input images in EPS format. I am using TeXnicCenter. When I use `latex->dvi` output profile, all of the EPS images show up fine. However when I want to take the final output by using `latex->pdf` output profile, no image shows up in the outputted PDF. Am I missing on something here?

Comment: I am using Texnic center for the conversion .In that I first use latex->dvi it works perfctly ...all figures in place etc.If I do latex-> pdf no figures show up.Someone told me I should use dvipdf but I dont know how to do that in Texnic Center

Comment: I have added your comment to your question. Unnecessary comments should be removed, including mine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need [ghostscript](http://mirror.cs.wisc.edu/pub/mirrors/ghost/GPL/gs902/gs902w32.exe) to let TeXnicCenter create a `latex->dvi->ps->pdf` output profile. Install the ghostscript first while I am updating my answer.

After installing ghostscript, you need do the following to force TeXnicCenter to recreate output profiles.

1. Open TeXnicCenter
2. Press `Alt+F7`
3. Backup the current output profiles by clicking `Export` (sounds like my name), follow the instructions until you save it.
4. After making a backup, click `Wizard` button, and follow the instruction.
5. Click `OK` to finish the process.

Comment: @rty: I noticed you created 6 questions but 4 of them have unclear status whether or not the solutions have solved your problem. It is recommended to revisit the questions you created.

Answer (score 2):

If you already have Ghostscript installed, there's an even easier way: The package [epstopdf](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/epstopdf). Simply add `\usepackage{epstopdf}` to your preamble and it'll take care of everything else, i.e. it'll convert all eps pictures to pdf and embed the created pdfs instead of the eps. pdfTeX can't embed eps graphics. The size, placement etc. of the pictures should remain the same.

Answer (score 1):

run your document with `xelatex` instead of `pdflatex`. Then everything should be fine. Ypu can easily create a new output profile for this. With `xelatex` the conversion is done on the fly.

Comment: I've been wondering about that, I don't think this will work: The great thing about XeLaTeX is that it takes Unicode input files. TeXnicCenter, however, can't handle Unicode input files. So it sounds like a bad match?

Comment: @doncherry: The _default_ is utf8, that's all. And if you want to use `latin1` then tell it `XeTeX` and it will handle it ...

Answer (score 0):

Convert the eps files to PDF and use pdflatex should solve this problem. The pdftex binary in tl 2010 and later will also convert eps file automatically.

Comment: Isnt there a better way to do it ?I already have everything properly aligned and in eps.Converting everything to pdf and then realigning would be too painful.

Comment: the figures ..because when I insert the pdf ones they are not properly aligned and bring in the same issues as with jpeg which had made me go to eps in the first place :-(

Comment: Post a second question with a minimal working example (and .eps and .pdf graphics) that shows the problem? I've never seen TL 2010 do that when converting a .eps file. There are several other ways of converting .eps to something else that won't work as well, though.