# Including pdf figures in Latex document using TexnicCenter

Tags: pdf, miktex, eps, epstopdf

I am sorry if I missed anywhere the obvious answer to my problem, but after searching several hours for a solution I am a bit lost...

I am using Texniccenter and MikTex under Windows Vista to create a pdf document with Latex.
Most of my images are in PS format and hence I use the LaTex=>PS=>PDF profile to create my document. If I however try to include a pdf image instead of a ps the document creation is interupted and no final pdf output is created.

My code looks like this:

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{image.pdf}
\caption[]{}
\label{}
\end{figure}
```

Is there anything obvious that I am missing here ?

Comment: The LaTeX=>PS step doesn't understand pdf images, and therefore fails. As far as I know, it is not possible to include both PS and PDF images in the same document. You either have to convert the PS/EPS files to PDF of convert the PDF to EPS.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Your question was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 8):

When compiling with `pdflatex` (via the `LaTeX => PDF` option) and including [`graphicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx), this automatically loads relevant [`epstopdf`](http://ctan.org/pkg/epstopdf) details. As such, (E)PS images should be converted on-the-fly to PDF equivalents. You *should* notice `file.eps` and `file-eps-converted-to.pdf` in your working folder.

So, if you're including *both* PDF and (E)PS images, use `pdflatex`.

From the `epstopdf` README:

> `epstopdf` is a Perl script that converts an EPS file to an
>   'encapsulated' PDF file (a single page file whose media box is the
>   same as the original EPS's bounding box). The resulting file suitable
>   for inclusion by PDFTeX as an image. The script is adapted to run both
>   on Windows and on Unix-alike systems.
>
> The script makes use of Ghostscript for the actual conversion to PDF.
>   It assumes Ghostscript version 6.51 or later, and (by default)
>   suppresses its automatic rotation of pages where most of the text is
>   not horizontal.
>
> LaTeX users may make use of the `epstopdf` package, which will run the
>   `epstopdf` script "on the fly", thus giving the illusion that PDFLaTeX
>   is accepting EPS graphic files.

<sub>You may have to include the `--shell-escape` flag, although it doesn't seem to be required on my system.</sub>

Comment: if I use Latex=>pdf I get "unknown file extension .ps" for all my PS images :(

Comment: @Christian: Have you tried some of the options on the UK TeX FAQ: [“Unknown graphics extension”](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=unkgrfextn)

Comment: @Christian You need to make `.eps` files, usually, as PostScript (`.ps`) files are not necessarily 'self-contained'.

Comment: See also [Converting eps to pdf](http://robjhyndman.com/researchtips/converting-eps-to-pdf/) and [EPS graphics with PDF(La)TeX](http://www.texdev.net/2009/09/28/eps-graphics-with-pdflatex/). It definitely works with MiKTeX 2.8 and later, or TeX Live 2009 and later. Since non-EPS PS files may not have a bounding box specified in the file, they're not automatically suitable for inclusion as figures. But since many PS files are actually conforming EPS files, you may not have that problem in practice.

Comment: Great, it works. Can combine eps and pdf figures through epstopdf.

Answer (score 3):

*This is actually an answer to Werner’s one.*

---

This worked fine here (Windows, MiKTeX 2.9) with `pdflatex`, I needed to load `epstopdf` *after* `graphicx` explicitly:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,epstopdf}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics[width={\textwidth}]{golfer.eps}
\end{document}
```

In TeXnicCenter one *must* add in the `LaTeX => PDF` output profile to the command line arguments either `--enable-write18` or `--shell-escape`. The former is the original MiKTeX command line option, but the latter works now as well. (These options are BTW described in the `epstopdf` manual.)

BTW, also related: [How to compile a document with EPS images using TeXnicCenter?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21118/how-to-compile-a-document-with-eps-images-using-texniccenter)

<sub>If you tend to upvote this answer, then consider the same for Werner’s contribution!</sub>

Comment: If `epstopdf` isn't automatically loaded, you probably have an outdated version of the TeX distribution. Update to MiKTeX 2.9 or use TeX Live 2011

Comment: @egreg: No, I recently had to install MiKTeX 2.9 from scratch. `\listfiles` tells me: “graphicx.sty 1999/02/16 v1.0f … graphics.sty 2009/02/05 v1.0o … epstopdf.sty 2010/02/09 v2.5”, `epstopdf --version` on command line “MiKTeX EPS-to-PDF Converter 2.9.3275 (MiKTeX 2.9)”.