# How do I embed vector graphics to LaTeX document

Tags: graphics, vector

I have a vector grahpics file. Could someone please help me embed a image into my LaTeX document ? I have no clue.

Comment: What kind of vector graphics file?

Comment: Are you using pdfLaTeX or plain LaTeX?

Comment: Is it possible to use a PDF as a container for a vector graphic and include the PDF then? Or can eps contain vector graphics?

Answer (score 27):

There are several vector graphics format in use these days by vector graphics packages, the most common ones being `pdf`, `eps`, and `svg`.

`SVG` tends to be the de facto internal working format for most of them these days, and it is a very good format for web applications as most browser will be able to display them natively. However, unfortunately, `svg` is currently not supported in LaTeX documents.

The historical format for vector graphics in TeX is `eps` and it is indeed the only format supported by the original latex, even for raster based images (indeed, all these file formats can contain both vector and raster based images).

With the `graphicx` package, and `pdflatex` (and newer incarnations such as `xelatex` and `lualatex`) you can now include raster files such as `jpg`, `png`, and so on, without having to put them in a `eps` container, and you can also include `pdf` files, however you lose the ability to include `eps` files.

Most graphics packages will allow you to export as eps or pdf so you can choose at the time which format you want. Alternatively, you can easily convert from one format to the other with command line tools such as `epstopdf`.

As for which format is better, this is open for debate, `pdf` is basically built on `eps` with more features such as embed fonts, including `ttf` and `otf` ones, and compressibility (so a `pdf` will usually be smaller than an `eps`) among others.  People will usually also have something installed on there computer that reads `pdf`, whereas, `eps` may be an issue.

Comment: _`svg` is currently not supported in LaTeX documents_!!! how is this even possible? Oh! perhaps relevant for `svg`: [How to include SVG diagrams in LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2099/how-to-include-svg-diagrams-in-latex)

Answer (score 1):

I guess you may want to export the graphics to the EPS format. EPS is fully supported by TEX in the figure environment.
You'll need this in preamble:

```
\usepackage{epsfig}
```

Then the figures are added as shown below:

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{ris00.eps}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: What about PDF? Why not use the more general [graphicx package](http://ctan.org/graphicx)?

Comment: In that case additional `\usepackage{epstopdf}` does the trick

Comment: @Alexandre With the last pdftex, I think you don't need  to add `\usepackage{epstopdf}`

Comment: The package `epsfig` is distributed only for compatibility with legacy documents and should not be used in new documents; `graphicx` is the real solution.

Comment: @Altermundus: I needed to add: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/52026/9237.

Answer (score 1):

There is one `svg.sty` that you have to import into your system latex directory {texmf/tex/latex/svg }. You can then use

1. `\usepackage{svg}`
2. `\includesvg[svgpath = images/]{example}` or
3. `\includesvg{example}` %file name is example without .svg extension.

Refer -

- https://github.com/FSund/latex-examples/tree/master/vector-graphics

Comment: The `svg` package uses `inkscape` to convert SVG file into PDF file before inclusion in the final document. It requires the `-shell-escape` option...