# How to get matlab plot in .eps format into the latex using epstopdf?

Tags: graphics, matlab, epstopdf

I want to enter my matlab plot into LaTeX. I am using the `graphicx` and `epstopdf` packages. But when I tried to make a pdf, the pdf was not created.  It shows a blank page and the following warning:

```
Package epstopdf Warning: No graphics package `graphic{s,x}' loaded.
)) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\graphicx.sty"
Package: graphicx 2014/10/28 v1.0g Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\graphics.sty"
Package: graphics 2016/07/10 v1.0t Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\trig.sty"
Package: trig 2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
```

How can I get rid of this problem?

Comment: Please help us help you and add a [minimal (non-)working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Things to check: The order of loading the packages matter, do you load `epstopdf` before or after `graphicx`? Do you have these packages installed in your distribution?

Comment: I am loading epstopdf before the graphicx package... Is that a problem?

Comment: Thanks @Huang_d. I changed the loading order and have got rid of the warning. Could you please post it as an answer, so that I can accept it.

Comment: As an aside, MATLAB will generate many different image types, so you could just create a .png or another extension that LaTeX will take naturally.

Comment: @sk8forether .eps allows for rescaling (encapsulated postscript, I _think_ it is a vector format). With pixel-based images you always have the problem of rasterisation and it is best to avoid rasterised images in documents to be printed (or scaled, for that matter).

Comment: @sk8forether --- png isn't a good format for plots or diagrams (it's a bitmap format; vector formats such as eps or pdf produce better results).

Comment: Yes, eps is a vector format according to [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52079/how-do-i-embed-vector-graphics-to-latex-document), which is probably a good reference for this discussion.  I was simply explaining another option _as an aside_, since there are many cases where an image will render "well enough" in png or some other format.  It depends on what you are trying to display, and personal preferences.

Comment: @sk8forether Please see https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7307/2693 on your edit to the answer. (For future reference.)

Comment: @AlanMunn Interesting... I was unaware of those spelling differences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some packages interact with each other and rely on a certain loading order. When you load them in the incorrect order, unexpected errors can occur. As a general rule, go from general package to specialised package; In your case, the `epstopdf` package should be loaded after the `graphicx` package. Another case where this matters is loading the `tikz` library after initialising the package.