# pdfpages & includepdf not working

Tags: pdfpages

I compiled the following file (through MiKTeX which I have just updated all files), and I do not get the `junk.pdf` file inserted.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
qwe
\includepdf[pages=-]{./junk.pdf}
\end{document}
```

The `.log` and `junk.pdf` file are there: [`junk1.log`](http://civil.colorado.edu/~saouma/junk2.log); [`junk.pdf`](http://civil.colorado.edu/~saouma/junk.pdf)

OK, yes it works with `pdflatex`, but I have to use `latex`->`dvips`->`ps2pdf` because of other constraints insertion of EPS figures). Beside, I do not know how to use the suggested `lastpage` option.

Using `\includepdf[nup=2x2,frame,pages={1-13}]{./junk.pdf}` I do correctly get 5 pages which should have included `junk.pdf`, but I get blank pages with a black dot in the center.

Comment: Another guess: Maybe the PDF file is broken. You should upload it somewhere, we can download it.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). Thanks for providing a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that), that is very helpful. Does the `junk.pdf` exist in the current directory?

Answer (score 5):

Note the warning issued by `pdfpages` in your `.log`:

```
Package pdfpages Warning: I cannot determine the number of pages of the
(pdfpages)                included document, while being in DVI mode. You
(pdfpages)                can use the option `lastpage' to give me a hint.
```

Being in DVI mode suggests you're compiling this using `latex`. You should compile using `pdflatex`.

If you have EPS figures that you want to include and feel that this forces you to use a `latex`->`dvips`->`ps2pdf` compilation sequence, consider reading the following posts:

- [Including PDF figures in LaTeX document using TeXnicCenter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/51917/5764)
- [Converting EPS to PDF](http://robjhyndman.com/researchtips/converting-eps-to-pdf/)
- [EPS graphics with PDF(La)TeX](http://www.texdev.net/2009/09/28/eps-graphics-with-pdflatex/)

Comment: Hum, using\includepdf[nup=2x2,frame,pages={1-13}]{./junk.pdf} I do correctly get 5pages which should have included junk.pdf, but I get blank pages with a black dot in the center

Comment: @victor: It seems like one of the linked posts (first) answered your question in terms of EPS figure inclusion while using `pdflatex`. As such, using `pdflatex` is the way to go and surely solved your problem. Please consider [accepting this answer](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852/5764) to close this question as solved.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the option `lastpage` as in,

```
\includepdf[lastpage=12]{Appendices/pdf_that_is_12_pages_long.pdf}
```

instead of specifying which pages.

Comment: One cannot use `\includepdf` when compiling the document with `latex` that accepts only EPS files for graphic inclusion.