# Insert PDF file in LaTeX

Tags: pdfpages

I'm using the following commands to add a `*.pdf` file into my report:

```
\usepackage{pdfpages}    
\includepdf[pages=-]{part.pdf}
```

I get the following message (and the PDF is not included):

> I will use a dummy `\includepdf` command(pdfpages) which will NOT insert any pages, because(pdfpages) you are producing DVI output.

Any idea how to solve the problem?

Comment: What are you using to compile your `.tex` file, `LaTeX` or `pdfLaTeX`?

Comment: I'm using pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (MiKTeX 2.9) (preloaded format=latex 2013.12.29) 
TEX maker

Comment: You're using `latex`, try with `pdflatex`. How do you run the compiler? command line, TeXworks, TeXStudio, Texmaker, ...

Comment: Do you have `\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}`?

Comment: I have \usepackage{graphicx} wihtout pdftex option.

Comment: Similar to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52190/pdfpages-includepdf-not-working

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.     A suggestion: Do us a favour and change your username to something more telling than "user1234".