# including .eps figures

Tags: graphics, miktex, eps

I'm trying to include .eps figures in my .tex file (I'm using MiKTeX 2.9).
I need to include graphics in this particular way:

```
\usepackage{graphics} % or graphicx 
...

\begin{figure}
 \caption{\label{tha_label} ....}
 \includegraphics{the_graphics.eps}
 \end{figure}
```

But that way doesn't work, because it produces the error `Unknown graphics extension: .eps`. Of course, I can use `\uspackage{eps-to-pdf}` and include my graphics without errors, but I do not need to use that usepackage (the method above is only allowed).  How can I do it?

Comment: If you can't use epstopdf and must include eps-figures you can't use pdflatex but must compile with latex + dvips (or dvipdfmx) (or xelatex).

Comment: If the problem with eps-topdf is you can't run external processes then (a) delete the extension and just have `\includegraphics{the_graphics.eps}` (that is a good idea anyway) and then make a .pdf version of teh eps before running pdflatex `ps2pdf the_graphics.eps`  then latex/dvips will use the .eps file and pdflatex will use the .pdf

Comment: Not to forget: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. But also a suggestion: Do us a favour and change your username to something more telling than "user1234".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using these commands in the cmd:

```
latex filename.tex
dvipdfm filename
```

I've compiled the codes

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{graphics} % or graphicx 
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
...
 \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

and they worked.

Comment: To add code highlighting as you can see from my edit, select the code and hit Ctrl + K, or click the button marked `{}` above the text field.

Answer (score 2):

You must …

… either compile your code in a mode, that produces DVI files and then further process the DVI file with `dvips`/`dvipdfm`/`dvipdfmx` (how it is done in Nguyen’s answer) or use XeLaTeX (produces interim XDVI files); VTeX seems also to be possible – cf. for this Heiko Oberdiek in [Graphics file extensions and their order of inclusion when not specified](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/72930/72939) – …

… or you use the package `epstopdf` *(that’s actually the name, without dashes!)*. This works, when you load this *after* `graphics`/`graphicx`. See also my answer: [Including pdf figures in Latex document using TexnicCenter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51916/52026) (the question title is misleading here).

Comment: Or convert `.eps` at the command line first to `.pdf`, then use pdfLaTeX

Comment: @JosephWright: Aah, yes.